# A question about div height and width - I want to have the screen full but at the same time the div to expand if the content is more than 100vh

Tags: css

```
width:100vw;
height:100vh;
```

I would like to have this as above but if the content of the div happens to be longer than 100vh (now or later), that the div height expands.

```
display:block;
overflow:auto;
```

I tried this but there seems to be scrolling inside the div. I do not want this.

I found the above solution in question #20590239 on here but 1) like I say I do not want to scroll within the div and 2) when I take height out that that answer suggests it messes EVERYTHING up!

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: `min-height: 100vh`?

Comment: @kukkuz That seems to stretch out the content of the other divs. :(

Comment: It is unclear to me what you want to do, could you explain further? A code snippet might be useful. To be more precise it is unclear whether you have a div that's full screen height and an interior div that should expand further, or if it's the same div that's full height and that needs to expand. I'm learning towards the latter, and then, as indicated by @kukkuz, ```min-height: 100vh``` seems to do the trick - what did you mean by it stretching out the content of the other divs?

Answer (score -1):

you need to target the specific div with either an ID or a css selector

```
#divID{
min-height: 100vh;
height: auto;
}
```